# ASP.NET Redirects to Login After Automatic Account Creation...Why?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication

I have a create_account.aspx page with a CreateUserWizard control on it. It has the LoginCreatedUser property set to true.

Once the account has been created and some further wiring up has occurred in CreateUserWizard_CreatedUser I do the following:

```
Response.Redirect("~/dashboard/default.aspx")
```

The individual is then redirected to the login.aspx page as if they are not authenticated? Why?

I have a suspicion that it may be related to the fact that default.aspx is in a sub-directory in which I have a web.config file stating,

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: is the user actually being authenticated after being created?

Comment: you need to look and see if the user is logged in/authenticated after the user is created. if the user is not logged in/authenticated then that is the cause of your problem and you will need to manually log in/authenticate the user after you create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try setting the CreateUserWizard ContinueDestinationPageUrl property to the required URL ie. `ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/dashboard/default.aspx"`. 
Can be done programatically also.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. It seems to me that the CreateUserWizard_CreatedUser is executed before the authentication occurs. When I changed over to using ContinueDestinationPageUrl it worked great.

Comment: Yeah, the order of events is a little funny.